# Are there any keyboard shortcuts for the auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed, when looking for an item, in this case gems, that searching multiple times usually yields a better offer than the one I saw before.

Sometimes it's a *screamin' deal*.  By the time I mouse over to hit purchase and buyout it's often sold.

Are there any keyboard shortcuts that can help me with this?

Comment: Question should be close as there is no longer an auction house for diablo 3.

Comment: Question should not be closed. See [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8451/50582) to your own meta question about D3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Based on my research, no.**

There is no mention in the [Diablo 3 Game Guide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/items/auction-house), or the [Diablo 3 Auction House FAQ](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-auction-house-regional-information), of any keyboard shortcut.  Moreover, there no other mentions of shortcuts in the general research I have done.  Hopefully, this will be added in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>RETURN</kbd> on the Auction House **search screen** after you have searched for an item will perform the same action as clicking on the 'Search' button, so once you've found the criteria you're looking for you can keep hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to refresh the list.

Comment: I have found that return closed the AH screen altogether :(

Comment: Was this immediately after opening the screen or after searching for an item? I've found it works fine after searching for an item.